# Matlab: What is a neutral element in the mean() function?

Tags: matlab, matrix, element, mean

I have a bunch of values in a 3-dimensional matrix, and I am finding the mean value of them:

```
mean(mean(mat))
```

Now, of different reasons I have to append some rows and elements to the matrix. But I want the mean value to stay the same - as if the added elements are neutral and do not inflict in the result.

Like when you multiply a bunch of values, you can multiply additional 1's without changing the result. And with addition you can add further 0's with no inflict.

What kind of value in Matlab can I assign to the new elements in the matrix to make the elements neutral when using the `mean()`?

**Note added**

The point is, when I am calculating the mean value I only have the new resized matrix to do it from. Therefore the added elements must be neutral.

I am thinking of something like `NaN`, but I had no luck with that since the mean value then also end up as `NaN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding values equal to the mean of the matrix without the added values will leave the new mean the same. (I hope that makes sense!). Point is to fill in and not change the new mean, use the current mean.

Alternatively, you can fill in with NaN and use the `nanmean` function.

Comment: But I haven't found the mean value beforehand... I am calculating it from the new resized matrix, where I simply want the mean to be the original mean from before the resizing.

Comment: You will need to calculate it beforehand in order to fill in the correct values.

Answer (score 0):

Add zeros to the matrix and rescale your mean to be the correct value.

i.e. if your original matrix A is n x m and you resize to B which is N x M then :

```
mean(mean(A)) = sum(sum(A)) / n x m

mean(mean(B)) = sum(sum(B)) / N x M
              = sum(sum(A)) / N x M   --- since we padded with zeros
```

Rearranging gives

```
mean(mean(A)) = mean(mean(B)) * ( ( N x M )/(n x m) )
```